# ng2-auto-complete ngModel does not change value

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am using the ng2-auto-complete module. I have a validation form and want to change the ngModel value, when the user selects an value from look up data (autocomplete).

I don´t want to change the value via a valueChangedEvent, because i use this module more than once. I want to bind my ngModel with the auto-complete value. How is this possible?

This is not working:

```
<div ng2-auto-complete 
  [source]="getValue('country')"
  placeholder="enter text">
  <input [(ngModel)]="person.country" />
</div>
```

if I select a value the person.country does not change.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a function on an input event like this :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="person.country" #myInput (input)="changeModel(myInput.value)"/>

// TS
changeModel(value: string) { this.person.country = value; }
```

Or you can use the OnChange implementation

```
export class MyClass implements OnChanges {
    // ...
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { this.person.country = changes.allResults.currentValue; }
}
```

Comment: I am using this auto-complete function 15 times. That means, i have to write for each entry a onchange method. This is exactly what i don´t want to do.

Comment: Or, since you probably learned how to code, you make a function with 2 paramters, the second one being the property you want to update.

Comment: Do you have a code example or a site where it is explained?

Comment: Man, seriously ? `(input)="changeModel(myInput.value, person.country)"` and the function `changeModel(value: string, property: string) { property = value; }`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this earlier, but i forgot to declare the value as property. the input event does not work if you select a data. I solved it with valueChangedEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code like this

```html
<div 
  placeholder="enter text">
  <input [(ngModel)]="person.country" ng2-auto-complete 
  [source]="getValue('country')" />
</div>
```

ng2-auto-complete tag and source should come along with input field.